# What's causing my UPDATE statement not to work?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Good evening all,

I'm using the following as an attempt to update records in my MySQL database, but the records aren't being updated and I'm not catching any exceptions either.  Your help would be kindly appreciated:

```
dbConn = New MySqlConnection("Server=" & FormLogin.ComboBoxServerIP.SelectedItem & ";Port=3306;Uid=trojan;Password=horse;Database=accounting")
    Try
        If dbConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            dbConn.Close()
        Else
            Try
                dbConn.Open()
                Dim dbAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("UPDATE customer " & _
                                                      "SET accountNumber= '" & TextBoxAccount.Text & "', nameLAST='" & TextBoxLastName.Text & "', nameFIRST='" & TextBoxFirstName.Text & "'" & _
                                                      "nameSALUTATION='" & ComboBoxSalutation.SelectedItem & "', nameCOMPANY='" & TextBoxCompanyName.Text & "', addressSTREET='" & TextBoxAddress1.Text & "'" & _
                                                      "addressSTREET1='" & TextBoxAddress2.Text & "', addressCITY='" & TextBoxCity.Text & "', addressSTATE='" & ComboBoxState.SelectedItem & "'" & _
                                                      "addressZIPCODE='" & MaskedTextBoxZip.Text & "', phone='" & MaskedTextBoxPhone.Text & "', fax='" & MaskedTextBoxFax.Text & "', email='" & TextBoxEmail.Text & "'" & _
                                                      "WHERE accountNumber='" & TextBoxAccount.Text & "';", dbConn)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("A DATABASE ERROR HAS OCCURED" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & _
                            vbCrLf + "Please report this to the IT/Systems Helpdesk at Ext 131.")
            End Try
            MessageBox.Show("Customer account SUCCESSFULLY updated!")
            Call lockForm()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("A DATABASE ERROR HAS OCCURED" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & _
                            vbCrLf + "Please report this to the IT/Systems Helpdesk at Ext 131.")
    End Try
    Call lockForm()
    dbConn.Close()
```

Comment: Are you looking at the correct database for your updates?  Is it occurring in test instead of live, etc?

Comment: Yes I am using the correct database.

Comment: You aren't getting any messageboxes to show?  You have stepped through the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MySQLCommand` instead of `MySQLDataAdapter`. You are defeating the purpose of using ADONet because still your code is vulnerable with sql injection. Make it parameterized. Below is a modified code from your code. It uses `Using-End Using` for proper handling of object disposal.

```
Dim ConnectionString As String ="Server=" & FormLogin.ComboBoxServerIP.SelectedItem & ";Port=3306;Uid=trojan;Password=horse;Database=accounting"
Dim iQuery As String = "UPDATE customer " & _
                       "SET accountNumber = @accountNumber, nameLAST = @nameLAST, nameFIRST = @nameFIRST, " & _
                       "    nameSALUTATION = @nameSALUTATION, nameCOMPANY = @nameCOMPANY, addressSTREET = @addressSTREET, " & _
                       "    addressSTREET1 = @addressSTREET1, addressCITY = @addressCITY, addressSTATE =  @addressSTATE, " & _
                       "    addressZIPCODE = @addressZIPCODE, phone = @phone, fax = @fax, email = @email               " & _
                       "WHERE accountNumber = @accountNumber"

Using dbConn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    Using dbComm As New MySQLCommand()
        With dbComm
            .Connection = dbConn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = iQuery
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountNumber", TextBoxAccount.Text )
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameLAST", TextBoxLastName.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameFIRST", TextBoxFirstName.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameSALUTATION", ComboBoxSalutation.SelectedItem)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameCOMPANY", TextBoxCompanyName.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@addressSTREET", TextBoxAddress1.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@addressSTREET1", TextBoxAddress2.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@addressCITY", TextBoxCity.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@addressSTATE", ComboBoxState.SelectedItem)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@addressZIPCODE", MaskedTextBoxZip.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", MaskedTextBoxPhone.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@fax", MaskedTextBoxFax.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text)
        End With
        Try
            dbConn.Open
            dbComm.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MessageBox.Show("Customer account SUCCESSFULLY updated!")
            Call lockForm()
        Catch( ex as MySQLException)
            MessageBox.Show("A DATABASE ERROR HAS OCCURED" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & _
                                vbCrLf + "Please report this to the IT/Systems Helpdesk at Ext 131.")
        Finally
            dbConn.Close()
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: John, thanks for your response.  I tried the code but it didn't work.  I got an exception that's saying "A fatal database error has occured" but doesn't provide any details beyond that.  Also, you repeated the parameter for accountNumber.  VB is throwing an exception that the parameter has already been declared.  Also, at the begin of the USING statement, you specify a variable "dmComm" the use "dbComm" at the WITH statement - is this just a typo?

Comment: @KismetAgbasican you try it again? i just updated the answer. is there any else error that has been generated?

Comment: It worked John.  VB still didn't like the repeat of the accountNumber parameter so I deleted that line and it worked as a charm.  Say, what did you change?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would use [ExecuteNonQuery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html) as you can't use a MySQLDataAdapter the way you are trying to use it. Also please use paramters as what you are doing opens you up to SQL injection attacks. And finally you don't need to update accountNumber because you are using that to find the row which you want to update!